# Command in the java classpath from eclipse doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-classpath

Can you tell me why the following classpath throws an error when I try to import my project into Eclipse?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

The error:

```
cannot nest 'myproject/src/main/java' inside library 'myproject/src'
```

Thank you

Comment: myproject/src is already listed as a source directory in your eclipse.  remove it (as a source directory) and use myproject/src/main/java as the source directory.

Comment: There's no such source directory on my project, just src/main/java.